is old evergreen builds tested on last mongodb server
When I see this link :
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/2.1.x/.evergreen/config.yml
I see that in the axes section that latest is tested :
 axes:
  - id: "version"
    display_name: "MongoDB Version"
    values:
      - id: "3.6"
        display_name: "3.6"
        variables:
          VERSION: "3.6"
      - id: "4.2"
        display_name: "4.2"
        variables:
          VERSION: "4.2"
      - id: "4.4"
        display_name: "4.4"
        variables:
          VERSION: "4.4"
      - id: "5.0"
        display_name: "5.0"
        variables:
          VERSION: "5.0"
      - id: "latest"
        display_name: "latest"
        variables:
          VERSION: "latest"

Does it mean that the current version of mongodb is tested against the old version 2.1 of the connector ?
Thanks

You're looking at the 2.1 branch, here is the file from the main branch: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/main/.evergreen/config.yml
Looks like main is tested with many more modern versions of Mongo.
